# Validating a URL from input

Tags: php, regex

I've got an input where the user is able to enter their website URL.

I can't use FILTER_VALIDATE_URL because that requires that the user types in `http://` before their URL. Some users might just type `www.website.com` or `website.com`.

How can I validate a URL with the following rules:

- doesn't require the user to have `http://`, `https://`, or any other form of this
- doesn't require the user to have `www.` before their link (example: just `website.com`)
- doesn't matter what domain extension is used
- allows links like `www.website.com/username` or anything alike to be used

How would this be done?

Comment: Rules vary from post to post.

Comment: so... read the posts and pick which one works best for you.  I had this exact problem two weeks ago.  I had to use a combination of things.  There's a _million_ answers to choose from.  It just takes a little research.  Anyone who answers this for you will just be doing the research for you.

Comment: I haven't found one that fits what I need.

Comment: I've found something that's almost what I need. How would I change this so that it accepts any domain extension rather than just .com, .net, etc? `$pattern = '/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+?\.(?:com|net|org|gov|edu|mil)|\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/';`

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

```
/(http[s]?:\/\/)?(www[\w]?\.)?[\w]*\.[\w]{2,3}[\/[\w]*]*$/i
```

this regular expression fits the following creteria:

1. `http://` or `https://` are optional but if user mentioned them, should be written in write way
2. `www(.).` is optional but if mentioned should be in right way
3. some parameters after the url are allowed. If you want just a devision after url, I mean www.facebook/user convert `*` at the end of above expression to `?`